# React JS : Unable to capture the edited value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am new to React JS. I am trying to capture the edited value from formcontrol in handle change and assign it to a state object and later retrieve assign it to a variable to pass it as a part of the query string to an API for updating the field, handle change is the function called from form-control to assign the edited value to a state object. I am unable to do so; please provide your inputs. Your help is much appreciated. I would like to follow the same for other fields too.

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import {
  Panel,
  Button,
  PageHeader,
  ControlLabel,
  FormControl,
  Pagination,
  Form,
  Accordion,
  Col,
  Radio,
  FormGroup
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import StatWidget from '../../src/components/Widget';
import CRUDTable,
{
  Fields,
  Field,
  CreateForm,
  UpdateForm,
  DeleteForm,
} from 'react-crud-table';

const DescriptionRenderer = ({ field }) => <textarea {...field} />;

const styles = {
  container: { margin: 'auto', width: 'fit-content' },
};

class displayDetails extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      updatecustomer: [],
      delcustomer: [],
      field1 = '',
    };

    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleCreate = this.handleCreate.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

  };

  handleChange (e) {
    this.state.field1 = e.target.value; // This isn't happening
  }

  render() {

    firstName=this.props.respData.FIELD1;
    lastName=this.props.respData.FIELD2;

    return (
      <div>
          <br></br>
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <StatWidget
            style="panel-primary"
            icon="fa fa-dollar fa-5x"
            count={this.props.respData.FIELD1}
            headerText="FIELD1"
            linkTo=""
          />
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <StatWidget
            style="panel-green"
            icon="fa fa-phone   fa-5x"
            count={this.props.respData.FIELD2}
            headerText="FIELD2"
            linkTo=""
          />
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <StatWidget
            style="panel-yellow"
            icon="fa fa-home fa-5x"
            count={this.props.respData.FIELD3}
            headerText="FIELD3"
            linkTo=""
          />
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <StatWidget
            style="panel-red"
            icon="fa fa-shopping-bag fa-5x"
            count={this.props.respData.FIELD4}
            headerText="FIELD4"
            linkTo=""
          />
          </div>
          <div>
          <tr>
              <td><h1>{this.props.respData.FIELD1} {this.props.respData.FIELD2}</h1></td>
          </tr>
          </div>
          <div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>FIELD 1</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl onChange={((e) => this.handleChange(this.props.respData.FIELD1))}
                  value={this.props.respData.FIELD1}
                  id="field1" name="field1"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
                </FormGroup>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <br></br>
          </table>
          </div>
          <br></br>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
   
export default displayDetails;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class displayDetails extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          state1: [],
          state2: [],
          state3: '',
          state4: '',
          state5: '',
          state6: '',
          state7: '',
          state8: '',
          state9: '',
          state10: '',

        };

        this.handleState1change = this.handleState1change.bind(this); 
        this.handleState2change = this.handleState2change.bind(this); 
        this.handleState3change = this.handleState3change.bind(this);
        this.handleState4change = this.handleState4change.bind(this);

        field1=this.props.respData.FIELD1;


        this.setState({state3:field1});

      };

      handlestate1change (e) {
       console.log('Inside handle state1 Change',e);
       this.setState({state3:e.target.value});
        console.log('state1 in handlestate1change',this.state.state3);
  }
      componentWillReceiveProps(){
        this.setState({state3:field1});
        console.log('newfirstName in Component will mount',this.state.state3);

      }


      render() {

      return(
                    <td>
                    <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                      <ControlLabel>Field1</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl onChange={this.handleState1change}
                        value={this.state.state3}
                        id="field1" name="field1"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>



      );

      }

      }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the state directly will not work. The only place you should be setting it directly, is to assign the initial state in your constructor. Everywhere else, you need to use [`this.setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), to notify your component to recheck the state for a possible rerender:

```
handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
        field1: e.target.value
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs I did that , But I am getting this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined , When I console log e in handle Change I get the value from form field that is this.props.respData.field1 and not the edited value from form control field. Please let me know how do I do this , I have done this too in constructor : this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

Comment: It's because you're passing the value directly here: `{((e) => this.handleChange(this.props.respData.FIELD1))}`. So it should be `handleChange(value)`.

Comment: Thanks again I did that , Now I am unable to edit that field in Formcontrol : <FormControl onChange={((e) =>this.handleChange(this.props.respData.FIELD1))} , handleChange(value){
    this.setState({
        field1: value
    });
}

Comment: I want the field to be editable , which is not happening now , The cursor's stuck right at the end of the field and I am unable to change the value and I want the changed value to be retrieved in handleChange function.

Comment: Any inputs on this ? Please , Your inputs are much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are in need of the `setState()` lifecycle method.

```
handleChange(e){

  this.state.field1 = e.target.value; // This isn't happening

  this.setState({
    field1: e.target.value
  }); // this will update state and trigger rerender
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs I did that , But I am getting this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined , When I console log e in handle Change I get the value from form field that is this.props.respData.field1 and not the edited value from form control field. Please let me know how do I do this , I have done this too in constructor : this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle I put together. On change of the input, the `value` property of state gets updated and is rendered on the DOM on the element with the class `answer`. Hope this helps! https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/322959/

Comment: Thanks a lot , That was very helpful , I shall post my updated code here in a while , I had to make changes to my code based on your suggestions depending on our use case , In our use case there are pre-populated values from api's json response and the new state variables are being initialized with the json response in componentwillMount() but componentWillMount isno longer recommended and I tried doing it in constructor but it doesn't server my purpose . componentWillMount holds state vallues of previous render too hence that is causing issues

Comment: Any inputs are appreciated ! Could you please suggest how do I initialize the state-objects in any other method apart from componentWillMount , Tried it in constructor not happeing , doesn't work in componentdidMount doesn't work , The problem with componentWillMount is the data from previous render is still there , How do I fix this . Your help is much appreciated

Comment: If you are populating state with data from an network request, I would recommend setting the state in `componentDidMount()`. This ensures you are making the request and populating the DOM elements only after you have rendered your React components. Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried it , doesn't work , the state objects end up being undefined even after initializing them in componentDidMount() where as in componentWillMount() they render the data from previous render too which is not what I want . Please suggest. Your help is much appreciated . I have posted the code below as the answer of how it is operataing

Comment: This is resolved , I used componentwillReceiveProps instead and it works fine .

Comment: Thanks for your inputs regarding this , It was very helpful and I have posted the working module , Could you please suggest how do I do the same for drop down as opposed to text boxes , I tried a similar approach and it didn't work ,I need to be able to edit and retrieve the selected values

Comment: The issue wrt drop down has been resolved , Thanks for all your inouts , I shall be posting the working code for drop down in a while